# How do I make my checkbox visible in only some rows of my listview?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a `checkbox` in each row of my `listview`.

Each row in the `listview` also shows a phone number, to the left of the `checkbox`.

I want the `checkbox` to be visible in only some rows of my `listview`, the rows where the phone number (`phoneNumberofContact`) is also a matching contact (the phone number is one in the `MatchingContactsAsArrayList` array list.

But all my checkboxes are invisible. Can you tell me how to put it right?

Here's my `getView()` in my custom adapter:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        System.out.println("getView number is :" + i + "convertView is : " + convertView);
        //we're naming our convertView as view
        //  View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            //if there is nothing there (if it's null) inflate the view with the layout
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.phone_inflate_listview, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no);

            viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);
            // viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //remember the state of the checkbox
            viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener((NewContact) _c);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
//        store the holder with the view
        final SelectPhoneContact data = (SelectPhoneContact) theContactsList.get(i);
        //in the listview for contacts, set the number
        viewHolder.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

        ////*********************

        //for every value in the allPhonesofContacts array list, call it phoneNumberofContact
        for (int number = 0; number < allPhonesofContacts.size(); number++) {

            phoneNumberofContact = allPhonesofContacts.get(number);

            System.out.println("SelectPhoneContactAdapter: phoneNumberofContact : " + phoneNumberofContact);

            //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
            if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(phoneNumberofContact))

            {
                viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            else {
                viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("SelectPhoneContactAdapter: allPhonesofContacts : " + allPhonesofContacts.size());


        viewHolder.check.setChecked(data.isSelected());



        viewHolder.check.setTag(data);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen

        return convertView;

    }
```

Here's my model:

```
public class SelectPhoneContact {

    String phone;

    public String getPhone() {return phone;}

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    //*****************************************
    //this is for the checkbox
    boolean selected = false;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected=selected;
    }


}
```

Comment: my spider senses are tingling on this line `MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(phoneNumberofContact)`

Comment: I have that line in another activity and it works as intended.

Comment: I cannot tell what you are trying to do in the "for" loop. There is no connection between `allPhonesofContacts` and `data`. However, looking at code, the check can be only visible when `allPhonesofContacts`'s last entry is in `MatchingContactsAsArrayList`. It is looping until the last entry without `break`, so the last entry is deciding whether check is visible or invisible.

Comment: @Emma In the for loop I am trying to see what contacts on the person's phone are also using my app, and then putting a checkbox beside those contacts. To be honest I find the whole getView() thing quite confusing. However based on your comment I have changed my code to along the lines of `for (int number = 0; number < MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size(); number++) {...if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(data.getPhone()))` and I am closer to what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Emma's comment. The only ***last*** value in the array takes into account.

Also, I would recommend you to optimize loop to prevent redundant iteration. Assume you should show checkbox if at least one value contains in MatchingContactsAsArrayList.

```
//for every value in the allPhonesofContacts array list, call it 
 phoneNumberofContact 
    for (int number = 0; number < allPhonesofContacts.size(); number++) {

        phoneNumberofContact = allPhonesofContacts.get(number);

        System.out.println("SelectPhoneContactAdapter: phoneNumberofContact : " + phoneNumberofContact);

        //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts 
        if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(phoneNumberofContact)) 

        { 
            viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break; // to exit the loop
        } 
         else { 
            viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments above and helpful `break;` tip for code optimization from Mike in his answer I figured it out. This will give me a `checkbox` beside the phone numbers in my `MatchingContactsAsArrayList` array list, and no checkbox beside the phone numbers that are not in that same array list.

```
 //for every value in the MatchingContactsAsArrayList array list...
    for (int number = 0; number < MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size(); number++) {

        //if a phone number is in our array of matching contacts
        if (MatchingContactsAsArrayList.contains(data.getPhone()))

        {
            viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("it's a match: phoneNumberofContact is : " + data.getPhone());
            break;

        }

        else {

            viewHolder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }
```